# use 'by'-style apply function but referencing other subsets

Tags: r, merge

All,

Consider a simple problem:

```
set.seed(1)   # if generating sample data, it's helpful to set a seed
idx <- rep(1:4,each=4)
c1 <- rnorm(16)
c2 <- rnorm(16)
tmp <- data.frame(idx,c1,c2)

for(i in 2:4){
    rows <- which(idx==i)
    tmp$delt[rows] <- (tmp$c2[min(rows)-1] - tmp$c1[min(rows)])/tmp$c2[min(rows)-1]
}

tmp
```

I would like to know if there is an efficient way to generate the delt column using an apply-class function. This example works well enough, but will likely get bogged down when implemented on a large data set.

Cheers

Comment: Did you realize that the first iteration of your for loop was making 8 non-NA assignments to delt? I think either a `by` or an `lapply(split(.),FUN)` would fail because you are indexing one behind the "lower-border" of the group of rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using `ave`

```
FUN <- function(i) { 
   i1 <- i[1]
   if (i1 > 1) 1 - tmp$c1[i1] / tmp$c2[i1 - 1] else NA
}
tmp$delt <- ave(1:nrow(tmp), tmp$idx, FUN = FUN)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can merge the table with itself. 
Especially if the data is large, data.table will be quite fast

```
# put your data into a data.table, keying by idx
library(data.table)
tmpDT <- data.table(idx,c1,c2, key="idx")


# merge to itself and calculate, using tail() and head()
tmpDT[ tmpDT[, list(c2prev = tail(c2, 1)), by=(idx+1)]
       , delt :=  (c2prev - head(c1, 1)) / c2prev  ]
```

Comment: thanks for the solution and feedback. @Grothendieck's method ended up being the quickest and most concise for my purposes.

Comment: @Aaron, no problem at all.  Glad you got your question resolved.  Please dont forget to hit the check mark on Gabor's solution

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base method:

```
dal <- c(FALSE, as.logical(diff(idx)))
dal_s <- c(as.logical(diff(idx)), FALSE)
d <- data.frame(idx=2:4,  delt=1-tmp$c1[dal]/tmp$c2[dal_s])
merge(tmp, d, all=TRUE)
```

Note that `(x - y)/x` = `1 - y/x`.    You could use the former expression above if necessary.